# Prefill date and currency field from one form to another form using public url method

Tags: cognito-forms

Please let me know how can we pass the dynamic value of currency and date in proper format for prefilling the form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You can use the [Prefill](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/65/data-integration/prefilling-a-form) method to pass data out of one Cognito Form, into another Cognito Form. We do have a [FAQ](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/119/faq/how-do-i-prefill-form-data-from-another-form) about setting this on between two forms.

Comment: But current date format is not supporting. So please let me know where I have to change date format and how.